# ArrayList for loop only removing only even indexes

Tags: java, arraylist

I expected this to print [] but it prints [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]. Can anyone explain why every index is not removed? 
Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> aL= new ArrayList<>();
        int[] aList = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        for(int i: aList){
            aL.add(i);}
        mystery(aL);
        System.out.println(aL);
    }


    public static void mystery(List<Integer> nums)
     {
         for (int k = 0; k < nums.size(); k++)
         {
         nums.remove(k);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger. It goes a long way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all the elements from your array, you have to start at the end and work backwards, otherwise your indices will get messed up.

Consider your array is as follows: `{0, 1, 2, 3}`
Now you want to loop through and delete starting with the 0th index. So the first loop happens, and now your array looks like this: `{1, 2, 3}`.

Next time, you loop through, you are deleting the 1st index, but this fails to take into account that the array shifted left, so now your array is: `{1, 3}`.

I think you can see the problem. So either you continue to delete at index 0: `nums.remove(0)` or you can start at the end of the array and work back.

Comment: Exactly, if you plan to traverse forward then you need to use another  empty array list to put the even indices, the other way around is to convert the ArrayList into an array.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you remove an element the list shifts left to fill that element from the higher indices, so when you then increment k you're skipping the element after the one you just removed.  You can remove from index 0 until the list is empty.

Comment: You beat me to it. haha This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually build my for loops backwards to avoid this problem.  It's especially helpful in situations where you want to delete a number of items sporadically from within a list without having to worry about reindexing causing you to remove the wrong items.  You can try this:

```
for(int k = nums.size()-1; k >= 0; k--) nums.remove(k);
```